# PyCharm unable to resolve dynamic references for multiprocessing module

Tags: python, pycharm

This is perfectly valid code:

```
globals().update({"variable": "val"})
variable
# do-something-with-variable
```

However, PyCharm is not able to recognise the variable:

[image]

I don't want to disable the marking of unresolved references; it is a very useful feature. I want PyCharm to recognise my variable. How can I do this? (even if it is a dirty trick for development that I will later erase in production)

### Explanation

I would not care about globals().update if it were not for that **Python's `multiprocessing` module from version 3.4 incorporates dynamic creation of variables** through a context class instead of defining them in the `__init__.py` file (see [this link](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/__init__.py)) For this reason, PyCharm **does not recognise the module's attributes at all**, so I have to be looking up docs constantly instead of making use of PyCharm's introspective features for this package, let alone not getting the `unresolved reference` error that makes me doubt constantly of whether I am getting the code right or not. Basically like writing code in Windows' notepad ;-)

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are going to fix this in the next PyCharm release by using a stub file... I believe it is possible to write your own stub files, so maybe you could do that. There seem to exist a 3rd party stub repository [that contains multiprocessing stub](https://github.com/JetBrains/python-skeletons/tree/master/multiprocessing) although it is 3 years old

Comment: Stubs for stdlib `multiprocessing` module [were enabled](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-30936) in 2018.3 version. EAP is [available](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/).

Answer (score 2):

Since Python is a dynamic language, it is not possible for PyCharm to check whether this is valid or not using static inferrence.

Consider the following:

```
globals = lambda: {}

globals().update({'variable': 'val'})

print(variable) # NameError: name 'variable' is not defined
```

Now that you overshadowed `globals`, this is not valid code anymore and PyCharm has no way to know.

The above being possible is a downside of dynamic languages: you cannot know if a program is valid before running it.

Comment: I know it is a bad practice, but I am afraid that that is how Python wrote its `__init__.py` method for the `multiprocessing` module.

Comment: See: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/__init__.py

Comment: For that reason, PyCharm is not able to detect my `multiprocessing` module properties for autocomplete, let alone stop marking them as unresolved references, making me constantly doubt whether I am getting it right.

Comment: So while your answer is correct for the general purpose, it seems Python devs have not taken it into account (it being terrible practice compensates with the benefits I suppose it gives them for dynamic environment setting).

Comment: That is actually way more interesting than I thought. Let me have a deeper look

Comment: @J.C.Rocamonde Although, the explanation why Pycharm cannot statically check that this is valid still holds.

Comment: Yeah haha the explanation sounds acceptable (the overshadowing example is a good point), however I can't find a solution for that specific Python module in the stdlib

Comment: @J.C.Rocamonde I had similar issues with libraries that do heavy use of metaclasses. Unfortunately, it's a downside of Python itself: you cannot infer whether the code is correct before running it. I fear your problem has no solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can add: `# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences` on the line above the line you want the unresolved reference inspection to be disabled.

It will not disable it anywhere else (from what I can see in my Pycharm 2018.2)